# Panel grid layout in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, grid-layout, jsf-2.2, panelgrid

I want a layout of `<p:panelGrid>` (or `<h:panelGrid>`) as shown in the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp2Cf.png) snap shot.

[image]

The following code,

```
<p:panelGrid style="width: 100%;">
    <p:row>
        <p:column rowspan="9">a</p:column>
        <p:column rowspan="7">b</p:column>
        <p:column>c</p:column>
    </p:row>

    <p:row><p:column>d</p:column></p:row>
    <p:row><p:column>e</p:column></p:row>
    <p:row><p:column>f</p:column></p:row>
    <p:row><p:column>g</p:column></p:row>
    <p:row><p:column>h</p:column></p:row>
    <p:row><p:column>i</p:column></p:row>
    <p:row><p:column>j</p:column></p:row>
    <p:row><p:column>k</p:column></p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

shows the layout as shown in the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRrUB.png) snap shot.

[image]

How can I achieve the layout as shown in first snap shot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
        <p:panelGrid style="width: 100%;">
            <p:row>
                <p:column rowspan="7">a</p:column>
                <p:column rowspan="5">b</p:column>
                <p:column>e</p:column>
            </p:row>

            <p:row>
                <p:column>f</p:column>
            </p:row>

            <p:row>
                <p:column>g</p:column>
            </p:row>

            <p:row>
                <p:column>h</p:column>
            </p:row>

            <p:row>
                <p:column>i</p:column>
            </p:row>

            <p:row>
                <p:column>c</p:column>
                <p:column>j</p:column>
            </p:row>

            <p:row>
                <p:column>d</p:column>
                <p:column>k</p:column>
            </p:row>

        </p:panelGrid>
```

Explanation:

[image]

Each row will try to place itself under the previous row where there is space for it (where a column is not spanning over multiple rows).

So after the first row: the next rows will be placed in the following positions:

[image]

But since you want the 6th and 7th row to have 2 columns, you need to add a second column to them.

Hopefully this clears it up a little.

Comment: This works but I don't understand the logic behind it :)

Comment: Glad i could help, the PanelGrid construction is a little tricky and i took me some time to get it as well... See my updated answer for explanation